# Error Handling for empty textboxes in aspnet and vbnet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ADD `button` in my `FormView` in `ASP.NET`. And I have txtName on it that should first check if the textbox is empty. If it was empty, the `ADD` button should message *Please fill up the form*.

I tried the traditional error handling in `vb.net` like

```
If txtbox.text = "" then
   error msg
end if
```

but it is not applicable when making a web page using ASP.NET backend: VBNET.

```html
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="92px" Width="835px" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="3" DefaultMode="Insert" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Horizontal" BackImageUrl= "howto.jpg" style="margin-bottom: 12px">
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name of Applicant" Font-Size ="10pt" Font-Names="Arial" ></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBday" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Birthday"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="Gender" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' Width="216px" Font-Size ="10" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBday" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("Birthday") %>' TextMode="Date" Width="216px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtGender" runat="server" Height="19px" Width="222px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Contact"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' Width="488px"></asp:TextBox>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("Contact") %>' Width="216px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEduc" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Educational Attainment"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblCourse" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Text="Course"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="txtEduc" runat="server" Height="19px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Education") %>' Width="495px">
                        <asp:ListItem>High School</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>College Diploma (2-3 years)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>College Undergrad (4-5 years)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Bachelor&#39;s Degree</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Master">Masteral</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Doctor</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCourse" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" Height="19px" Text='<%# Bind("Course") %>' Width="216px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="Insert" Font-Names="Berlin Sans FB Demi" CommandName="Insert" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="CANCEL" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Berlin Sans FB Demi" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" CommandName="Cancel" />

                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
            </asp:FormView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't show that alert on a webapp, but you can use javascript in order to do it.

In code behind declare this function:

```
Public Sub AlertMessage(ByVal mensaje As String, ByVal pag As Page)
        pag.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "showConfirm", "Alerta('" & mensaje & "');", True)
End Sub
```

Then call it from your *ADD* button like this:

```
If txtbox.text = "" then
   AlertMessage(msg, Me.Page)
end if
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I've learn  from some research that there is other way for error handling using ASPNET. I used the validation control and validation group.

```html
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup ="FillUp" runat="server" ControlToValidate ="txtName" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><br />
          
 <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="ADD" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="FillUp" Font-Names="Berlin Sans FB Demi" CommandName="Insert" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGz9I.jpg)

I also add this code in my Web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

I know, what you are thinking,"This guy has a poor desig", lol, well the important is you know the code xD